# How to determine $c$ so that $x^2-2xc+9x^{8/3}=2-2c$ has a single root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> How to determine $c$ so that this equation has a single root?
> $$x^2-2xc+9x^{8/3}=2-2c$$

I've tried with Geogebra, and I know it's around 1.14

The same number appears on WA

But how to find the exactly value for c?

Comment: This is just an idea; I don't know if it will work.  It appears from a sketch that when there is a single solution, the graph will have a double $0$ there.  So taking derivatives, $24x^{5/3}+2x-2c=0$  Now multiply both sides by $x$ and eliminate the $x^{8/3}$ terms from the two equations.  That gives you a quadratic in $x$, which you can solve for $x$ in terms of $c$.  Substitute this into the equation for the derivative, and see if you can solve for $c$.  I doubt it will be possible to solve in closed form, but maybe you'll get something that's not too bad numerically.

Comment: Okay, I understood you, and I've reached c as a complex number :( 

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equation like this
$$9 x^{8/3}+x^2-2= 2 c x-2c$$
now set
$$\begin{cases}
y=9 x^{8/3}+x^2-2\\
y=2 c x-2c\\
\end{cases}$$
The first equation represent a curve, similar to a parabola. The second represents the set of lines passing through the point $P(1,0)$ with slope $2c$.

The derivative of the first equation is:
$$y'=24 x^{5/3}+2 x$$
Therefore a tangent line in a generic point $(x_A,y_A)$ has equation
$$y - (9 x_A^{8/3}+x_A^2-2)=(24x_A^{5/3}+2x_A)(x - x_A)$$
In order to pass through $P$ we substitute $P$ coordinates and get
$$-(9 x_A^{8/3}+x_A^2-2)=(24x_A^{5/3}+2x_A)(1 - x_A)$$
Expand and reorder, we get the equation
$$-24 x_A^{5/3}+15 x_A^{8/3}+x_A^2-2x_A+2=0$$
which has two real solutions
$$x_1=0.216028;\;x_2=1.55825$$
if $x=0.216028$ then $y=-1.80211$.

Substitute in the equation of the line and get $c_1=1.14935$

if $x=1.55825$ then $y=29.8007$ and $c_2=26.6912$

Comment: Thank you, for me that's a clever solution

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

Let $$f(x)=x^2-2xc+9x^{\frac 83}-2+2c$$

near $ \pm \infty$, we have
$$f(x)\sim 9x^{\frac 83}$$

$$\implies \lim_{|x|\to+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$$

So, the equation $ f(x)=0 $ will have only one root $ \alpha $ if and only if
$$f'(\alpha)=0=2\alpha-2c+24\alpha^{\frac 53}$$

Answer (score 1):

At roots, we have

$$c=\frac{x^2+x^{8/3}-2}{2(x-1)}.$$

A plot reveals that this curve is "hyperbolic-like" and has two stationary points, which corresponds to two single roots.

We find them by solving

$$(x^2+x^{8/3}-2)'(x-1)-(x^2+x^{8/3}-2)(x-1)'=0$$

or

$$15x^{8/3}+x^2-24x^{5/3}-2x+2=0.$$

there are two distinct solutions in $x$, giving you two $c$.